# Redux container does not know what "this" is

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have been trying to figure out why my container does not know what "this" is.

If I change the container to a component then the it all works correctly.

This Component works perfectly and changes the state when it hits the store

```
    class testCard extends Component {


       test= (event) => {
           console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"); // Shows
           this.props.testAction(); // This works
       }

       render(){
       return (
       <Card>
           <CardActionArea onClick={this.test}>
               ... // Card stuff
           </CardActionArea>
           <CardActions>
       </Card>)
       }
   }


   const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
       return {

      }
   }

   const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
       return bindActionCreators(
       {
            testAction:   testAction()
        }, dispatch)
   }
   export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (testCard);
```

Below the code does not know what 'this' is and will throw an error.

```
   const testCard = (props) => {

    let test= (event) => {
        console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"); // Shows
        this.props.testAction(); // This errors saying cannot find props of undefined
    }


    return (
    <Card>
        <CardActionArea onClick={test}>
            ... // Card stuff
        </CardActionArea>
        <CardActions>
    </Card>)
  }


  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     return {

     }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
     return bindActionCreators({
         testAction:  testAction()
     }, dispatch)
   }
   export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (testCard);
```

Comment: Is that second example supposed to be a functional component? It starts off looking like one, but then says `render() {` which i would expect to be a syntax error. If it is a functional component, then there's no `this`. Just access `props.testAction`, not `this.props.testAction`

Comment: There are no "instances" of functional components, so there is no use for  `this`. `render() {...}` in the second example looks like a syntax error, the code shouldn't even run.

Comment: Yes, sorry removed the render. That was left over from converting between the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you have to call props.testAction() in your 2nd example.
It uses ES6 arrow function.
https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4

Also when you use arrow functions for react components you don't need the render() method (render is needed when you use class based component i.e extends React.Component, then you need to implement it), all you need in arrow function is to return your result i.e jsx data.

https://medium.com/@yassimortensen/container-vs-presentational-components-in-react-8eea956e1cea

Comment: *"Also when you use arrow functions for react components...."* The same applies to all functional components no matter how they are defined.

Comment: Brilliant, I was missing I needed props.action. It now works when I change it to that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes.

```
   class testCard extends React.Component {

    test = (event) => {
        console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        this.props.testAction()
    }

    render(){
    return (
    <Card>
        <CardActionArea onClick={test}>
            ... // Card stuff
        </CardActionArea>
        <CardActions>
    </Card>)
    }
   }

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     return {

     }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
     return bindActionCreators({
         testAction:  testAction()
     }, dispatch)
   }
   export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (testCard);
```

To give you further insight onto why "this" was giving you an error. It's because "this" always points to the closest object. Because you were not using a class-component (an object), it pointed to the **global window object** by default, which does not have a property of **props**. Which is why you were getting the error "cannot find props of undefined". You can work around this by a class-component in combination with arrow functions.

If you want to use the props passed down to non-class component, you would simply use:

`props.nameOfValuePassedDown()` instead of `this.props.nameofValuePassedDown()`

Comment: @bulb, let me know if you have any questions. "This" is often a pretty darn difficult concept.

Answer (score 1):

It is important that you have to know what props is.
Most components can be customized when they are created, with different parameters. These creation parameters are called props .
With props we can send and receive data from **component to component**.
For enough understanding props, refer to react tutorial Tic-Tac-Toe game.

I hope this will be your help.